# How to add control to form at runtime, and validate?

Tags: angular

I would like to add a control to a form during a runtime. I've tried the following:

```
_.forEach(this.parameters, (param,i)=>{
        var control = {};
        control['param'+i] = ['', Validators.required];
   this.form.addControl('param'+i,this._formBuilder.control(control));
    })
```

This works fine - it adds the control to the model. However, it doesn't trigger the validation again.

I've tried this:

```
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

however, this doesn't have to any effect